# How to set value to array if name have index in javascripts?

Tags: javascript

I want to set value to array if name have index, I have data like this:

```
[
    {
        "column": "created_at[0]",
        "name": "created_at[0]",
        "type": "range",
        "value": "2022-12-26 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "column": "created_at[1]",
        "name": "created_at[1]",
        "type": "range",
        "value": "2023-12-26 23:59:59"
    },
    {
        "column": "email",
        "name": "email",
        "type": "like",
        "value": "aa@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

and I want to modify the name and value to array result if name have index, the result should like this:

```
[
    {
        "column": "created_at",
        "name": "created_at",
        "type": "range",
        "value": ["2022-12-12 00:00:00", "2023-12-12 23:59:59"]
    },
    {
        "column": "email",
        "name": "email",
        "type": "like",
        "value": "aa@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

I have try to do that whit this, but it doest work

```
const res = array?.reduce(
      (accumulator, value) => ({
        ...accumulator,
        [value.name?.split("[").shift()]: value.value,
      }),
      {}
    );
    console.log(res)
```

Comment: What happens, in case there is all of a sudden `created_at[2]`; does the value-array of a 'range'-type items then just contain the values of the `created_at[0]` item and the `created_at[2]` item? Are 'between'-type items which are intended to be collapsed into a single 'range'-type item always strictly consecutive?

Comment: Instead of editing my answer, please only edit your question and let me know the changed values. You changed your input to between and back to range and mine to between. What is the actual value? range or between? Not that it matters. I do not look at the value but look to see if it already has a '['

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this - note the [Nullish coalescing assignment ??=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)

```js
const grouped = array.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => {
  const baseName = name.split('[')[0];
  acc[baseName] ??= { // using the Nullish coalescing assignment
    column: baseName,
    name: baseName,
    type: name.includes('[') ? 'range' : 'like',
    value: []
  };
  
  if (name.includes('[')) { // it's a range
    acc[baseName].value.push(value);
  } else {
    acc[baseName].value = value;
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(grouped);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
  const array = [{
      "column": "created_at[0]",
      "name": "created_at[0]",
      "type": "range",
      "value": "2022-12-26 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "column": "created_at[1]",
      "name": "created_at[1]",
      "type": "range",
      "value": "2023-12-26 23:59:59"
    },
    {
      "column": "email",
      "name": "email",
      "type": "like",
      "value": "aa@gmail.com"
    }
  ]; </script>
```

Faster example?

```js
const grouped = array.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => {
  const splitIndex = name.indexOf('[');
  const baseName = splitIndex === -1 ? name : name.substring(0, splitIndex);
  const isRange = splitIndex !== -1;

  let entry = acc[baseName];
  if (!entry) {
    entry = acc[baseName] = {
      column: baseName,
      name: baseName,
      type: isRange ? 'range' : 'like',
      value: isRange ? [] : value
    };
  }

  if (isRange) {
    entry.value.push(value);
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script>
  const array = [{
      "column": "created_at[0]",
      "name": "created_at[0]",
      "type": "range",
      "value": "2022-12-26 00:00:00"
    },
    {
      "column": "created_at[1]",
      "name": "created_at[1]",
      "type": "range",
      "value": "2023-12-26 23:59:59"
    },
    {
      "column": "email",
      "name": "email",
      "type": "like",
      "value": "aa@gmail.com"
    }
  ];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {
        "column": "created_at[0]",
        "name": "created_at[0]",
        "type": "between",
        "value": "2022-12-26 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "column": "created_at[1]",
        "name": "created_at[1]",
        "type": "between",
        "value": "2023-12-26 23:59:59"
    },
    {
        "column": "email",
        "name": "email",
        "type": "like",
        "value": "aa@gmail.com"
    }
];

const result = data.reduce((r, item) => {
  const idx = item.name.lastIndexOf('[');
  if (idx === -1) return r.arr.push(item) && r;
  const name = item.name.slice(0, idx);
  let found = r.map[name];
  found ? r.arr.push({column: name, name, type: 'range', value: [found.value, item.value]}) : r.map[name] = item;
  return r;
}, {arr: [], map: {}}).arr;

console.log(result);
```

```
` Chrome/120
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander             1.00x  |  x1000000  123  124  129  130  131
mplungjan             1.18x  |  x1000000  145  147  150  150  150
mplungjan (faster?)   1.35x  |  x1000000  166  167  175  176  186
-----------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```
` Firefox/121
------------------------------------------------------------------
Alexander             1.00x  |  x10000000  729  753  784  799  801
mplungjan (faster?)   1.55x  |   x1000000  113  118  122  132  146
mplungjan             3.42x  |   x1000000  249  261  262  263  267
------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        "column": "created_at[0]",
        "name": "created_at[0]",
        "type": "between",
        "value": "2022-12-26 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "column": "created_at[1]",
        "name": "created_at[1]",
        "type": "between",
        "value": "2023-12-26 23:59:59"
    },
    {
        "column": "email",
        "name": "email",
        "type": "like",
        "value": "aa@gmail.com"
    }
];

// @benchmark mplungjan 

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => {
  const baseName = name.split('[')[0];
  acc[baseName] ??= {
column: baseName,
name: baseName,
type: name.includes('[') ? 'range' : 'like',
value: []
  };
  
  if (name.includes('[')) { // it's a range
acc[baseName].value.push(value);
  } else {
acc[baseName].value = value;
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

Object.values(grouped);

// @benchmark mplungjan (faster?)

Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { name, value }) => {
  const splitIndex = name.indexOf('[');
  const baseName = splitIndex === -1 ? name : name.substring(0, splitIndex);
  const isRange = splitIndex !== -1;

  let entry = acc[baseName];
  if (!entry) {
entry = acc[baseName] = {
  column: baseName,
  name: baseName,
  type: isRange ? 'range' : 'like',
  value: isRange ? [] : value
};
  }

  if (isRange) {
entry.value.push(value);
  }

  return acc;
}, {}));

// @benchmark Alexander

data.reduce((r, item) => {
  const idx = item.name.lastIndexOf('[');
  if (idx === -1) return r.arr.push(item) && r;
  const name = item.name.slice(0, idx);
  let found = r.map[name];
  found ? r.arr.push({column: name, name, type: 'range', value: [found.value, item.value]}) : r.map[name] = item;
  return r;
}, {arr: [], map: {}}).arr;

/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: Let's compare readability to speed here? ;)

Comment: @mplungjan in my code transform functions should be as short and fast as possible even at the cost of readability. btw in FF there's 3.5x speed difference.

Comment: I have not succeeded in copying your benchmark code. Can you add my second example to the tests, please?

Comment: @mplungjan actually slower in chrome but faster in firefox. i see that you create a new object for a non-range item. that slows down. it's not clear though how the data will be used though, usually i try to reuse the old data as much as possible since it's usually read-only.

Comment: Ok. I have spent enough time on this... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    "column": "created_at[0]",
    "name": "created_at[0]",
    "type": "between",
    "value": "2022-12-26 00:00:00"
  },
  {
    "column": "created_at[1]",
    "name": "created_at[1]",
    "type": "between",
    "value": "2023-12-26 23:59:59"
  },
  {
    "column": "email",
    "name": "email",
    "type": "like",
    "value": "aa@gmail.com"
  }
];

const res = data.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
  const nameParts = item.name.split("[");
  const baseName = nameParts[0];

  if (nameParts.length > 1) {
    const index = parseInt(nameParts[1].replace("]", ""));
    if (!accumulator[baseName]) {
      accumulator[baseName] = {
        column: baseName,
        name: baseName,
        type: "range",
        value: Array(index + 1).fill(null).map(() => null)
      };
    }
    accumulator[baseName].value[index] = item.value;
  } else {
    accumulator[baseName] = { ...item
    };
  }

  return accumulator;
}, {});

const resultArray = Object.values(res);
console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: Perhaps give some description of what you wrote?